# How to remove the prefix of a table for a Django model?

Tags: django, model

I create a new Django app (not project) called Bussinesses, then add following class to the `models.py`.

```
class Bussinesses(models.Model):
    business_email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    contact_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    contact_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

If I use Bussinesses directly, the Django will access the "bussinesses_bussinesses" table in the database, which obviously does not exist.

Because the table "bussinesses" is also used by another APP, So can't rename it.
I want to know how to use the Django model without using table prefix, and I don't want to use the raw database API directly.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Just use the [model meta options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/).

```
class Bussinesses(models.Model):
    business_email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    contact_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    contact_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "bussinesses"
```

BTW *businesses* is misspelled. Since you're specifying the name of the table you don't have to give your model the same name as the table, so if the table name is misspelled and you can't easily fix it, you can at least change the name of your class to the proper spelling of *businesses*. I would also get rid of the pluralization, and make it `class Business`. Finally it's not uncommon when using Django or Rails on an existing database to need to set a custom table name for *every* table.

Comment: You're welcome. mgibsonbr's tip on the managed property is also a good one, and might be useful in developing your app.

Answer (score 12):

As an aside, if you want to change *(or remove)* the prefix for ***all*** tables you can provide your own meta-class. This is useful if you have multiple cases like `Businesses` where you'd just like the class and table name to be the same.

For instance the following code prefixes all tables with `FOO_` instead of *`appname_`*:

```
class MyModelBase( ModelBase ):
    def __new__( cls, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs ):
        if name != "MyModel":
            class MetaB:
                db_table = "FOO_" + name

            attrs["Meta"] = MetaB

        r = super().__new__( cls, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs )
        return r       

class MyModel( Model, metaclass = MyModelBase ):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Businesses( MyModel ):
    ...
```

Comment: I had to use more explicit class references, `models.base.ModelBase` for `ModelBase` and `models.Model` for `Model`.  However, it still won't work for me.  When I use `MyModel` as a basis for my class (like `Businesses`), I get the error: `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'id' in class 'Businesses' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'MyModel'.`  That error didn't occur when my class was based on `models.Model`.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the table name in the model's Meta class, using the [`db_table`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table) property.

Also, if you're using a database table that already exists, you might also want to take a look at the [`managed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#managed) property. After setting a model to unmanaged `syncdb` will not affect it (if you reset your app, for instance), but you can still use Django's ORM normally.

Answer (score 1):

you can actually set the table name manually using the meta class, more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/