# Django how to customize table name and foreign key field

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

Working with existing database. All existing tables has named space prefixed `tbl_`. How can I create model class or configure django settings to prefix `tbl_` before querying or syncing.

Also each child table having foreign key on fields, each field has prefixed with name space `id_[table_name]`. I want to configure for foreign key too.

Comment: Have a look here, maybe it leads into the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849666/how-to-remove-the-prefix-of-a-table-for-a-django-model

Comment: Thanks @Jingo, it solves for table name. But still I need more solution for foreign key field name!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#database-representation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Configure your models to use the table and column names you want. Here's an example:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tbl_category'

class Entry(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, db_column='id_tbl_category')
    contents = models.TextField('Contents')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tbl_entry'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @sjaensch, it works. One more thing, can I configure Django to always prefix `tbl_` for each table while quering...

Comment: As far as I know that's not possible.